# Появление элемента при прокрутке страницы

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Помогите нужен появляющийся блок при прокрутке страницы до определенного места. Написать написал и все работает за исключением что изначально элемент виден а он не должен пока крутить вниз не начнут. Раз прокрутили все работает правильно и блок пропадает. Как только перезагрузил страницу блок виден снова, пока крутить вниз не начнешь сразу пропадает и появляется на нужном месте по скролу вниз. Помогите братцы ? Изначально чтоб не виден был. Пока до определенного места вниз не прокрутят страницу.

```
#fixed1 {
  display: table;
  height: 120%;
  width: 240px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 85%;}

.fixed1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<div id="fixed1">
  <div class="fixed1">
  <button onclick="hideme(this)">ЗАКРЫТЬ?</button>

<!-- leftkvadro -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-8511102670529458"
     data-ad-slot="6373749854"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function hideme(obj){
    obj.parentNode.style.display = "none";
}</script>
<script>
jQuery(function(f){
    var element = f('#fixed1');
    f(window).scroll(function(){
        element['fade'+ (f(this).scrollTop() > 200 ? 'In': 'Out')](500);          
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="fixed1" style="display:none">
```

и/или

```
jQuery(function(f){
    var element = f('#fixed1');
    f(window).scroll(function(){
        element['fade'+ (f(this).scrollTop() > 200 ? 'In': 'Out')](500);          
    });
    f(window).scroll(); // !!!
});
```

Comment: С Div не сработало а вот второй вариант заработал Спасибо Братцы !

Comment: @Helpsetup На здоровье. Обратите внимание на знак "галочка" слева от ответа. Судя по принятым Вами ответам (их нет), до сих пор Вы его не замечали ).